# How to find the velocity and acceleration when the distance travelled in $t$ seconds is given by $x = 3t^3 - 4t^2 + 6t - 5$

Tags: calculus

> The distance, $x$ metres, travelled by a body in $t$ seconds is given
> by
>
> $x = 3t^3 - 4t^2 + 6t - 5$
>
> Find the velocity and the acceleration when (i) $t = 0$, (ii) $t=2.5$.

---

I differentiated $x$ and evaluated the resulting expression at $0$ to obtain:

$9(0)^2-8(0)+6 = 15$

Similarly, for $2.5$ I obtained:

$9(2.5)^2-8(2.5)+6 = 42.25$

After this, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What have you tried? There will be no answer back to you unless you show your try properly.

Comment: A good place to start would be with the definitions of velocity and acceleration.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  You should edit your question to show what you did rather than stating that in the comments where it might be missed.

Comment: Just differentiate the expression you got for velocity one more time to get acceleration. It's that simple. Then substitute for the numerical values of $t$.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: $9(0)^2 - 8(0) + 6 \neq 15.$  Similar to velocity being the first derivative, acceleration is the second derivative.  By the way, is it possible that there is a typo in the original formula?  That is, how is the distance traveled after $(0)$ seconds equal to $(-5)$?  That seems nonsensical, while the alternate specification, that the **position** after $(0)$ seconds is $(-5)$ is (much) more sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that velocity is defined as the *rate of change of position* as a function of time and, similarly, acceleration is defined as the *rate of change of velocity* as a function of time.

Hence, $v(t) = x'(t)$, and $a(t) = v'(t) = x''(t)$ (where $x$ gives the position as a function of time).

Then, simply plug the given $t$ values into your expressions for $v$ and $a$ (i.e. evaluate $a(t = 0)$, $a(t = 2.5)$, $v(t = 0)$, and $v(t = 2.5)$).